# Template function call with constexpr return function value C++

Tags: c++, templates, enums, constants, constexpr

Here is my code :

```
enum class MYENUM {
A = 0, B = 1
};

template<MYENUM T>
void somefunc() {
    std::cout << "working" << std::endl;
}
struct A {
    constexpr MYENUM mytype() {
        return MYENUM::A;
    }
};
struct B {
    A obj;
    void f() {
        somefunc<obj.mytype()>(); //'this cannot be used in a constant expression'
    }
};
```

In trying to call `somefunc` from the function `f` from `struct B`, I get an error saying `'this cannot be used in a constant expression.'` Is what I am asking for impossible to do?

Comment: Note that `obj.mytype()` would work *if obj was constexpr*.

Answer (score 4):

> Is what I am asking for impossible to do?

Yes and no. `this` is a run-time value, and indeed cannot be used in a constant expression.

But in your case it seems `mytype()` doesn't need to be a member function, so you can declare it `static`.

```
struct A {
    static constexpr MYENUM mytype() {
        return MYENUM::A;
    }
};
```

Now it will work. ([Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cso7Wh))

Comment: What if instead of making it static, use if else and call the fcn manually? Would this be bad practice? Eg. if (x == MYENUM::A) somefunc<MYENUM::A>();

Comment: An if-else or switch would evaluate at run-time instead of compile-time. If the return value of `mytype()` indeed differs per instance of `A`, then yes that would be the only way to implement it.

Comment: @jasbindra00 That works. That is basically what you'd have to do if the function wasn't constexpr. Remember that each template instantiation is a *completely different function* - `somefunc<MYENUM::A>` is a completely different function from `somefunc<MYENUM::B>`, so the compiler has to know which one you want to call, that's why you can't do `somefunc<somethingThatIsntConstexpr()>`. When you use `if`, the compiler generates all the functions in the if and the program decides which one to call.

Comment: @user253751 I think the use of a template here is inappropriate for me. I think I will just go with a run time evaluation by asking for an addition MYENUM argument instead. The reason as to why I had chosen a template to do this is because it would eliminate the possibility of the user inserting a non listed ENUM type (eg static_cast<MYENUM>(100000)). But now when contronted with the if/else solution, it seems to defeat the purpose of a function.. I think I will just throw an exception should the user insert a non listed enum type. Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: Yes, user input should be validated as soon as possible, before it goes further into program logic.